# Update only one field in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

How could I update only one field of my table by EF core?
In another language how could I translate below SQL statement into EF Core  :

UPDATE table_name SET column1 = value1 WHERE condition;

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update it by below code

```
 public async Task updateUserInfo(string token,long  userId)
        { 
User user = _userRepository.GetDbContext().Set<User>().Find(userId);

            user.token= token;

            _userRepository.GetDbContext().Set<User>().Attach(user);

            _userRepository.GetDbContext().Entry(user).Property(x => x.token).IsModified =true;
           await _userRepository.GetDbContext().SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I searched it on google and found a small example about this.

```
 var stud = new Student(){ StudentId = 1, Name = "Bill" };
    
    stud.Name = "Steve"; 
    
    using (var context = new SchoolContext())
    {
        context.Update<Student>(stud);
    
        context.SaveChanges(); 
    }
```

I hope it will help your problem.

Comment: Do not provide link only answers, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Do not remove the link entirely, though. This is someone else's code that you're pasting, so you need to acknowledge that in your answer.